# WebDeploy package contains personal folder path

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, webdeploy

When I use the Web Deploy Package publish method to publish a ASP.NET MVC website in Visual Studio 2019, the package contains multiple references to my computer and personal folder paths.

For example, the systemInfo.xml file contains:

```
<systemInfo osVersion="6.3" winDir="C:\windows" machineName="[***MYCOMUTERNAME***]" processorArchitecture="x86" msdeployVersion="1.0" buildVersion="7.1.2606.1250">
```

And the *.sourceManifest.xml file contains:

```
<IisApp path="C:\Users\[***MYUSERNAME***]\Source\Repos\myproject\obj\x64\Release\Package\PackageTmp" />
```

The package still works, but if I want to use this package to distribute the software, how can I build it so that it does not contain personal information?

Answer (score 1):

Web deploy packag always contain the physical path of your project and machine name automatically no matter you generate package from VS or webdeploy. So if you need to hide [***MYUSERNAME***], please move your project to another path which doesn't contain username.

web deploy package can be pushed remotely so you don't have to worry about the machine name.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/ff356104(v%3Dvs.110). If you don't want to expose the machine name, you can edit system.info manually.